# Algorithm to find words that uses most letters that I have from the word list

Tags: algorithm

I am developing a game I need an algorithm to find words that use most letters.

L,A,B,K,C,O,L,N,A,E words that can be constructed with these letters

> ABACK ABLE ACNE ALACK ALAN ALBA ALEC ALOE ALONE ANAL ANKLE BAAL BACK BACON BAKE BALANCE BALE BALK BALL BALLON BANAL BANCO BANE BANK BEACON BEAK BEAN BECK BECKON BELL BLACK BLACKEN BLANK BLEAK BLOC BLOCK BLOKE BOCK BOLE BONE CABAL CABLE CAKE CALL CANAL CANE CANOE CELL CELLO CLAN CLANK CLEAN CLOAK CLONE COAL COKE COLA COLE CONE EBON ELAN KALE KANA KANE KENO KNELL KNOB KNOLL LABEL LACE LACK LAKE LANCE LANE LANK LEAK LEAL LEAN LOAN LOBE LOCA LOCAL LOCALE LOCK LONE NALA NECK NOBLE NOEL OAKEN OCEAN OLLA ONCE

I need an algorithm that finds words combination that uses most of the letters. letters can be used once.
I can find it with brute force algorithm I can take out one word and try to find another word with the letters I have left. But I want to build more elegant algorithm.

```
public class FindBetsWords {

    private static String wordsStr = "ABACK,ABAFT,ABATE,ABBA,ABBE,ABBOT,ABET,ABLAZE,ABLE,ABOUT,ACME,ACNE,ACTA,ACTUAL,ACUMEN,ACUTE,AFFABLE,AFFECT,AFLAME,AFLOAT,ALACK,ALAMO,ALAN,ALBA,ALBUM,ALBUMEN,ALEC,ALFA,ALLOT,ALMA,ALOE,ALOFT,ALONE,ALTO,ALUM,AMAZE,AMAZON,AMBLE,AMEN,AMOUNT,AMULET,ANAL,ANKLE,ANTE,ATOLL,ATOM,ATONE,AUNT,AUTO,BAAL,BABA,BABE,BABEL,BABU,BACK,BACON,BAFFLE,BAKE,BALANCE,BALBOA,BALE,BALEFUL,BALK,BALL,BALLET,BALLON,BALLOT,BALM,BANAL,BANCO,BANE,BANEFUL,BANK,BANTAM,BATE,BATEAU,BATMAN,BATON,BAUBLE,BEACON,BEAK,BEAM,BEAN,BEAT,BEAU,BECK,BECKON,BEFALL,BELL,BELT,BEMOAN,BENT,BETA,BLAB,BLACK,BLACKEN,BLAME,BLANK,BLANKET,BLAZE,BLAZON,BLEAK,BLEAT,BLENT,BLOC,BLOCK,BLOKE,BLOT,BLUE,BLUFF,BLUME,BLUNT,BOAT,BOATMAN,BOATMEN,BOCK,BOLE,BOLT,BOMB,BONE,BOULE,BOUNCE,BOUT,BUCK,BUCKET,BUCKLE,BUFF,BUFFALO,BUFFET,BULB,BULK,BULL,BULLET,BULLOCK,BUMBLE,BUNK,BUNT,BUTE,CABAL,CABLE,CABMAN,CABMEN,CAFE,CAKE,CALF,CALL,CALM,CALOMEL,CAME,CAMEL,CAMEO,CANAL,CANE,CANOE,CANT,CANTO,CATE,CELL,CELLO,CELT,CENT,CENTO,CENTUM,CLAM,CLAN,CLANK,CLEAN,CLEF,CLEFT,CLOAK,CLOMB,CLONE,CLOT,CLOUT,CLUB,CLUE,COAL,COAT,COBALT,COBB,COFFLE,COKE,COLA,COLE,COLLET,COLT,COLUMN,COMA,COMB,COMBAT,COMBE,COME,COMET,COMTE,CONE,CONFUTE,CONTE,COTE,COUNT,COZEN,CUBE,CUFF,CULL,CULT,CUTE,EBON,ECLAT,ELAN,ENACT,ETNA,FABLE,FACE,FACT,FACTUAL,FAKE,FALCON,FALL,FALLEN,FAME,FANE,FATAL,FATE,FATEFUL,FAUCET,FAULT,FAUN,FAUNA,FEAT,FELL,FELLA,FELON,FELT,FETAL,FLACK,FLACON,FLAKE,FLAM,FLAME,FLANK,FLAT,FLAUNT,FLEA,FLECK,FLOAT,FLOCK,FLOE,FLOUNCE,FLOUT,FLUE,FLUENT,FLUKE,FLUME,FLUTE,FOAL,FOAM,FOCAL,FOEMAN,FOLK,FOMENT,FONT,FOUL,FOUNT,FUEL,FULL,FUMBLE,FUME,FUNK,KALE,KANA,KANE,KATA,KENO,KENT,KNACK,KNELL,KNELT,KNOB,KNOCK,KNOLL,KNOT,KNOUT,KNUCKLE,LABEL,LACE,LACK,LACUNA,LAKE,LAMA,LAMB,LAMBENT,LAME,LAMENT,LANCE,LANCET,LANE,LANK,LATE,LATEN,LEAF,LEAK,LEAL,LEAN,LEANT,LEFT,LEMAN,LEMON,LENT,LENTO,LLAMA,LOAF,LOAM,LOAN,LOBE,LOCA,LOCAL,LOCALE,LOCATE,LOCK,LOCKET,LOCUM,LOFT,LONE,LOUT,LUCE,LUCENT,LUCK,LUMEN,LUNA,LUNE,LUTE,MACE,MACK,MACON,MAKE,MALE,MALL,MALLET,MALT,MANA,MANE,MANFUL,MANO,MANTEAU,MANTEL,MANTLE,MANTUA,MANUAL,MATE,MAUL,MAUN,MAZE,MEAL,MEAN,MEANT,MEAT,MELL,MELON,MELT,MELTON,MENO,MENTAL,MENU,META,METAL,MOAN,MOAT,MOCK,MOLE,MOLL,MOLTEN,MONK,MONTE,MOTE,MOTEL,MOUE,MOULT,MOUNT,MUCK,MUCKLE,MUFF,MUFFLE,MULE,MULL,MULLET,MUTABLE,MUTE,NABOB,NALA,NAME,NATAL,NEAT,NEBULA,NECK,NOBLE,NOEL,NOME,NOTA,NOTABLE,NOTE,NUKE,NULL,NUMB,OAKEN,OAKUM,OATEN,OATMEAL,OCEAN,OFFAL,OFTEN,OLLA,OMEN,ONCE,OUNCE,OUTBACK,TABLE,TABLEAU,TABU,TACK,TACKLE,TACO,TAKE,TAKEN,TALA,TALE,TALK,TALL,TALON,TAME,TANK,TEAK,TEAL,TEAM,TELA,TELAMON,TELCO,TELL,TOKEN,TOLE,TOLL,TOMB,TOME,TONE,TUBAL,TUBE,TUCK,TUFA,TULE,TULLE,TUMBLE,TUNA,TUNE,UNABLE,UNCLE,UNCO,UNFELT,UNLOCK,UNMAKE,UNTO,ZEAL,ZEALOT,ZETA,ZONE";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String availableLetters = "LABKCOLNAEMFKUTFZB";
        char[] availableLettersCharArr = availableLetters.toCharArray();

        String[] words = wordsStr.split(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to see where I will use this algorithm you can download zade games kelime101 from google play.

Comment: for example if algorithm picks ball and acne    there are C , O  are left

Comment: it can pick  BANK and LOCAL only letter E remains you can test your algorithm with these words. I can get available words that we can build with the letters I hava but algorithm should pick the words so  less letters should remain

Comment: If the comments are necessary to describe the problem, it could be useful to edit the question and add them to the question.

Comment: Do you have a list of the constructed words available? Or are you constructing all the possible combinations and then checking against a dictionary for valid words?

Comment: I have all the words that could be constructed with these letters. Currently I am taking one of longer words. and I remove letters which are in that word. and I  check whether one of the other words can be constructed with the remaining letters. It works for the game but we could write better algorithm so least letters would  left unused

Answer (score 0):

This is a bin packing problem: if each word is represented by a vector of 27 numbers, one for the number of each letter in that word, what you want is maximizing I such that `sum(Vk 0<k<i)<= W`   where `W` is the same vector for your initial letters

Answer (score 0):

Just use `HashSet<char>`. For each word clear the container and put each character of that word into this set.

That guarantees that there will be no duplicates. Then by calling `hashset.size()` (or equivalent from the language u use).

By keeping the biggest size set initially to 0 you can compare for each word.

```
   size = 0 
   bestWord = null;
   for(w : wordList){
       hashset = new HashSet<char>()
       for(c : w){
          hashset.insert(c)
       }
       if(hashset.size() > size){
           size = hashset.size()   
           bestWord = w
       }
   }
   print(bestWord)
```

Comment: You can test your algorithm which words it finds. I did not  understand it.  How it finds the words.

Comment: Its a pseudocode, not compliable ;). It finds one word with the biggest number of distinct characters in it. e.g. AAB - 2chars, AABDB - 3 chars, ABCD - 4 chars etc. In this case it would return ABCD. By inserting twice to a set the same element you cause no change in its state. e.g. set.insert("a"); set.insert("a") - set.size() still equals to 1 although be performed 2 inserts.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a weighted set packing problem, with the weight being the length of string, as pointed out by David in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969950/how-to-form-maximum-number-of-1s-from-non-overlapping-bitsets). It is an NP-complete problem. Both approximation and optimal solutions could be found in [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2020/3050714/). But I haven't had time to read it.