# How to form maximum number of 1s from non overlapping bitsets

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, bitset, bin-packing

> Given N number of bitsets consisting of M bits, choose K bitsets such that there is no multiple 1s occurring in the same position. What is the maximum number of 1s that can be formed?

Example:

```
N = 5, M = 6
001100
011010
100100
111001
001010
```

The answer would be combining `011010` and `100100`, where the answer is 5.

I expect a polynomial time solution, although I am not sure whether it is possible. The problem is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802323/algorithm-to-find-words-that-uses-most-letters-that-i-have-from-the-word-list) with probably better phrasing.

Comment: Why the `dynamic-programming` and `graph-algorithm` tags?

Comment: @Olivier I would imagine there might be something to do with connecting 1s bit and apply dynamic programming, or have some connections with it. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Please post that as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [weighted maximum set packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) where each bitset is interpreted as a set, and the weight of each set is its cardinality.